# The "execution" in Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am learning Spring AOP by following the tutorial.

At chapter [Spring AOP capabilities and goals](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-introduction-spring-defn), it said that:

> Spring AOP currently supports only method execution(1) join points

But at the chapter [aop-pointcuts-designators](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-pointcuts-designators), it support the following pointcut expressions:

```
execution(2)
within
...
```

What is the different meaning of the two execution marker by (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 0):

What that quote means is that Spring can only intercept method invocations. [Aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) typically has a much wider reach. AOP join points can be any piece of code, method invocation, exception thrown, exception caught, variable assignment, etc. Spring's AOP however is limited by the Java language and its features. As such, it can only handle method invocation join points. Continue reading how Spring implements AOP features with proxies.

The quote above is completely unrelated to the type of pointcuts.

The `execution` (2) is a [pointcut designator.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

> **execution** - for matching method execution join points, this is the
>   primary pointcut designator you will use when working with Spring AOP

Comment: In fact I know what does the execution(1) mean, there are other type of join points like `field` and etc, spring just support 'method execution`. But what confused me is the execution(2) in the pointcut expression, what does that mean?

Comment: @hguser Please see my edit. Is that what you needed?

Comment: The pointcut designator contains "execution,within,this....", since Spring support `execution` only, then I am not sure if the designator `execution` make any sense, and make `execution` compared with `within,this...` will make it look like `within,this...` are not used for method execution(But in fact, they still support method execution only, isn't it?)

Comment: @hguser No. As I said, the two uses of the term `execution` are completely different. **All of Spring's AOP capabilities work with method invocations.** There are, however, many ways to describe which methods to intercept. You can describe them by their `execution`, you can describe them where they are (`within`, ex. within some package), you can describe them by what type the object they were invoked on is (`this`/`target`), you can describe them by their annotations, etc. That's what Pointcut Designators are for. Continue reading the link I posted.